# How to restore transaction in android in-app purchase version 3 application?

Tags: android, ios, transactions, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have used in-app purchase version 3. I don't know **how to restore transaction** means when user **purchased one feature** then how to store that transaction and how to get that transaction when user again used(like first installed then uninstalled and finally again installed) then i want to restore the transactions which he has purchased.

**I seen in iOS they are used some thing like StoreKit** then it will store the all transactions, and we can retrieve and check whether user is purchased feature or not, like that anything is there in Android means in iOS these are handled by **AppStore so Google Play Store** also has this feature or not.

So if i want to restore the transaction then I have to store these **transaction in permanent storage like cloud storage** and retrieve from cloud storage.Is this the only solution or any solutions are there?.If it is then how can i achieve this restore transactions feature?.

Please tell me.

Comment: when I used test purchase it is automatically restoring the purchase, it shows like product already purchased. So like that also it will update real transaction may I know the confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer my self i.e if my product is managed, then product(purchase) will be handled by google, **managed means if it once purchased then it is purchased for that account(like gmail account)**, so if user is uninstalls it and again install then that product is purchased(based on account Id). So this will be handled by google.